# When two buttons are pressed at same time

Tags: c#

I have a little problem. I have a form, which is my login form. Then I also have another form, which is my add user form. When I click on the login button for the login form, it needs to check if the shift and control keys are both held down on the same time. Ff both of them are not pressed, then the add user form should not open. but if they are both pressed down and the login button is clicked, it should show the form.

What I have:

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == (Keys.Control & Keys.Shift))
{
    //Show the form
}
```

But this is not working.

When I have:

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
{
    //Show the form
}
```

Then it works.

How can I achieve this with both buttons pressed down, control and shift?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `Keys.Control | Keys.Shift`.

---

This is a flags enumeration; each value is represented by a separate bit in the underlying `int`.

`Keys.Control & Keys.Shift` results in a zero value - e.g. if `Control` is `0001` and `Shift` is `0010`, the bitwise-`&` is `0000`.

`Control.ModifierKeys` will be `0000` if and only if the user is holding *no* modifier keys down, so the `==` will only result in `true` if the user isn't holding anything down.

`Keys.Control | Keys.Shift`, on the other hand, results in a value that says "both these flags" - e.g. if `Control` is `0001` and `Shift` is `0010`, the bitwise-`|` is `0011`.

`Control.ModifierKeys` will be `0011` if and only if the user is holding both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> down, so the `==` will only result in `true` in this case.

---

Alternatively, you could break this down as

```
bool ctrlIsHeldDown  = (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control;
bool shiftIsHeldDown = (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift)   == Keys.Shift;
if (CtrlIsHeldDown && shiftIsHeldDown)
{
    ...
}
```

The `(value & x) == x` construct checks whether an individual flag `x` is set, and after that it's jsut standard boolean logic.

Comment: thats a OR statement. then when I press control on its own, it will go in, and when i press shift, on its own, then it will also go in. I want it to execute only when both of them is helf down.

Comment: @Bebbie7 it is a "bitwise or" that is computed before checking equality.

Comment: @Bebbie7 I've added some more detail; the OR essentially works the opposite way in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift))
{
    //Show the form
}
```

Hope this help.