# Basic Calculator Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, forms, button, textbox, calculator

I'm making a basic calculator on windows forms c#, everything's running the way I need it to, except that I need to know what I can do to show an "error" message on the textbox for the user everytime they  press two buttons in a row, instead of having the program crash and not work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398699/when-two-buttons-are-pressed-at-same-time

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536368/detect-when-two-keys-are-pressed-at-the-same-time

Comment: Why shouldn't the user be allowed to click two buttons in a row? Like pressing `1` and then `1` again for the number `11`.

Comment: @GrantWinney please check the second link probably duplicate to that i guess.

Comment: @KarlAnderson My bad, what I meant was two buttons such as + or - or * etc... the numbers can be pressed as many times as the user wants to

Comment: @GrantWinney how can I do that? I'm sorry I am just starting to learn to program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a variable in which you hold the last operator was clicked by user and whenever a button is clicked , you check; if it is operator (like + ,- , & ...) and current variable's value is not equal by new one , you update this variable else you could ignore the button clicked.